# Referencing List Positions

Tags: python, list

I have a list with letters like so which I have created through an Input statement:

```
Letters = [A, B, C, D, A, C, D, F, G, A, C, D]
```

I have then create a Letters list (see below) by enumerating through the letters list and appending all the Alphabetical Letters that were used to create the original sequence of letters.

```
LettersUsed =     [A,B,C,D,F,G]
# indexOfLetters: [0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

I then stored the index of each letter (within the `LettersUsed` list) into a new list called `indexOfLetters` by using the built-in `in` method.

So, what I want to do now is re-create the original sequence within the Letters list, but replace it by the index of the Letter in the `LettersUsed` list. So for example:

```
#original sequence: [A, B, C, D, A, C, D, F, G, A, C, D]
newsequence = [0 1 2 3 0 2 3 4 5 0 2 3]
```

I just don't know how I can do this bit.

Comment: Why do you want to use lists. Using dictionaries its very simple

Answer (score 5):

You can crate a dictionary of sorted list with a dict comprehension the get the related index :

```
>>> d={j:i for i,j in enumerate(sorted(set(Letters)))}
>>> 
>>> [d[i] for i in Letters]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3]
```

The `set` just preserve the unique elements and `sorted` will returns q sorted list of your set. then you can loop over the `enumerate` of that sorted list to create the dictionary :

```
>>> sorted(set(Letters))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G']

>>> d
{'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 3, 'G': 5, 'F': 4}
```

Comment: can you please explain briefly what the above does? what does the set command do?

Comment: set() removes duplicates from a list

Comment: will the above only work with words? I have tested using words and is giving a very unusual output. For example when doing the above for: Words = ['My', 'Name', 'Is', 'Name', 'Is'] it produces the output: [1, 2, 0, 2, 0]....

Comment: @PythonNewBee It will works for words but the sorted function will sort the words lexicographicaly.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, makes perfect sense now.

Comment: For words how do I amend the function in order for it not to sort lexicographicaly. So words = ['My', 'Name', 'Is', 'Name', 'Is'] output is [0, 1, 2, 0, 1] and not [1, 2, 0, 2, 0]. I have removed the sort function but still does the same.

Comment: @PythonNewBee This is a pretty different question! i suggest to ask another question about it with the code that you have so far its a good question!